# Connecting a Thundebolt 3 docking station to a Windows desktop via optical 15m Thundebolt optical cable

Tags: usb-c, thunderbolt, docking-station, optical-cable

I have a Windows 10 Pro 64 bit gaming desktop behind a concrete firewall (physical), and I want to transfer two monitors pluss USB signal out on the other side of the concrete wall.

My idea was to buy a Thunderbolt docking ([ICY-BOX IB-DK2288AC](https://www.proshop.no/Dokkingstasjon/RaidSonic-ICY-BOX-IB-DK2288AC-docking-station-USB-C-32-Gen-2-Thunderbolt-3-Thunderbolt-4-4-x-HDMI-4-x-DP-GigE/3183008)) and a [Corning optical Thunderbolt 3 cable](https://www.corning.com/microsites/coc/ocbc/Documents/OEM-062-A4-AEN.pdf) that is 15 meter long. In stead of routing multiple different cables, I want to use the docking station outside as an extension of the back panel of my desktop and only use a single Thunderbolt cable to manage it.

When testing the docking I first used a thunderbolt 1 m cable that was included with the docking and a HDMI monitor connected to the docking. This resulted in image on my screen, for any USB-C type ports on my PC. All good so far.

However, when switching the included cable with my brand new 15 meter Corning AOC-CCU6JPN015M20 cable, no signal is transported to the HDMI monitor.

I get that Thunderbolt is a hard standard to do creative setups with, but I cannot se why this would not work. Are there any software tweeks I could try? I use the newest driver for my docking station and Graphics card (GeForce RTX 2080Ti). I have a Thunderbolt port on the graphics card, a USB-C port on a dedicated PCI-E card and one last on the mainboard [ASUS ROG STRIX Z390-F GAMING](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z390-f-gaming-model/). All those ports give me a living monitor with the 1 meter original cable, but not with the optical one. I have also tried using the optical cable in both directions without any more luck

Any idea why an optical cable specified to support the Thunderbolt 3 standard refuse to connect my computer to the docking? Is there anything else I could try, either with software or hardware.

Comment: In the specs of the cable you've linked, it's written that it's only recommended for MacOS. That's probably an elegant way to say It won't work on PC. Also it's clearly stated that it won't work on USB-C, which is a different standard.

Comment: OK :/ That is sad :( 
I was of the impression that all thunderbolt 3 cables would support USB-C, even though the oposit is not the case. Apparently this is my problem. 

Are there any more pitfalls to watch out for if I look for an optical USB-C cable like this? https://www.ipcstore.com/club3d-usb32-g2-typec-act-opt-av-mm-20m-usb-cable-32-gen-2-31-gen-2-usb-c-black-3882836#specification

Comment: If you really cant get your TB ports to work with the cable you have, given your docking station I'd buy a USB-4 cable so you have full Displayport and Thunderbolt support. Such as this one: https://www.bkstec.com/products/3m-fiber-optic-usb-4-0

Comment: the cable you found instead uses Displayport alt mode, which limits your flexibility, also I'm not sure your docking station supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thunderbolt/comments/kvuxi3/corning_optical_thunderbolt_3_cable_windows/). It says:

> I connected with some representatives at Corning, who confirmed that they are marketing these cables for use with Mac, as during their testing, they found Windows support to be hit and miss depending on the exact models of hardware being used.

It further states that an update of Thunderbolt drivers made the cable usable for that person.

So your way to go is to update the TB drivers for your hardware, and try your luck.

---

**Edit**: [This other thread](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1453422-corning-optical-thunderbolt-3/) gives the additional information:

> I changed which pcie slot the [thunderbolt] card was in and it started working.

**Edit 2**: Also note that the spec sheet you linked clearly states that the cable does not support native USB, so you need to use a Thunderbolt port.